# Get key of an value within object of object with multiple key and value pairs using javascript

Tags: javascript, object, key, key-value, nested-object

I have an nested object

```
var obj = {"bn_IN":
        {"status":"SUCCESS","language":"BENGALI","message":"Translated successfully"},"sq_AL":
        {"status":"SUCCESS","language":"ALBANIAN","message":"Translated successfully"},"af_ZA":
        {"status":"SUCCESS","language":"AFRIKAANS","message":"Translated successfully"},"da_DK":
        {"status":"SUCCESS","language":"DENMARK_DANISH","message":"Translated successfully"},
        "ar_DZ":{"status":"SUCCESS","language":"ARABIC","message":"Translated successfully"}}
```

I need to get key "bn_IN" from "BENGALI" value

Tried:

```
Object.keys(obj.filter(k=>obj[k]===BENGALI.toUpperCase())
```

Couldn't filter

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear but I assume that you need the key whose value is an object and that contains a "language" key and that "language" key should have a value of "BENGALI".

```
//In the case of multiple keys
var obj = {"bn_IN":{"status":"SUCCESS","language":"BENGALI","message":"Translated successfully"},"sq_AL":{"status":"SUCCESS","language":"ALBANIAN","message":"Translated successfully"},"af_ZA":{"status":"SUCCESS","language":"AFRIKAANS","message":"Translated successfully"},"da_DK":
        {"status":"SUCCESS","language":"DENMARK_DANISH","message":"Translated successfully"},
        "ar_DZ":{"status":"SUCCESS","language":"ARABIC","message":"Translated successfully"}}

var keys=[]

for(key in obj){
     if(obj[key].language==="BENGALI") keys.push(key)
}

// In case if you know that key is unique

var obj = {"bn_IN":
        {"status":"SUCCESS","language":"BENGALI","message":"Translated successfully"},"sq_AL":
        {"status":"SUCCESS","language":"ALBANIAN","message":"Translated successfully"},"af_ZA":
        {"status":"SUCCESS","language":"AFRIKAANS","message":"Translated successfully"},"da_DK":
        {"status":"SUCCESS","language":"DENMARK_DANISH","message":"Translated successfully"},
        "ar_DZ":{"status":"SUCCESS","language":"ARABIC","message":"Translated successfully"}}

var key="";

for(key in obj){if(obj[key].language==="BENGALI") key=key}
```